# Ruby/Rails - How to include something from the join table on as_json method option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a many to many relationship. I am storing a status string on the join table.

Example: Order has many Items on it. Items are fixed. On the OrdersItems table we store a string called item_status. I want to return the Order using as_json.

```
  def as_json(options={})
    opts = {
      only: PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES,
      methods: [:items],
    }.merge(options){|k,o,n|o|n}
    super(opts)
  end
```

This works, except I want to add that item_status to each hash in the items array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can include associated models as part of the options given to  `to_json`, with more or less the same configuration options.

```
opts = {
  only: PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES,
  include: {
    items: {
      only: [:status]
    }
  }
}
```

See: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json